# iOS: Adding Qt to an existing Xcode project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, qt

I want to use some Qt core functionality in an existing iOS 7 Xcode project (similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668604/adding-qt-to-xcode-project)). I do not need Slots or Signals.

Is there a way to import the Qt libraries, and use them in the existing Xcode project?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried QT for iOS?

[QT for iOS](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/ios-support.html)

Comment: Yes, I checked this. But following this procedure requires a full re-setup of my existing project. My existing iOS xCode project consists of several other objective-c subprojects, frameworks, storyboards, and resources.